# How to get the samAccountName from a csv file exported from Teams via powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have exported a CSV file from Microsoft Teams and got the data that I required after running this command:

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\TeamsUserActivity.csv" | 
Where-Object { $PSItem.DisplayName -notlike "*-*" } | 
Select-Object -Property DisplayName,'LastActivity (UTC Time)' | 
Sort-Object -Property 'LastActivity (UTC Time)' -Descending | 
Export-Csv -Path "C:\TeamsUsers.csv"
```

This displays the following:

```
DisplayName        LastActivity (UTC Time)
-----------        -----------------------
Tom Smith          2020-04-16T01:00:47Z
Joe Bloggs         2020-04-16T01:00:47Z
Harry Briggs       2020-04-16T01:00:47Z
Jeff Kerry         2020-04-16T01:00:47Z
Jane Briggs        2020-04-15T23:17:29Z
Betty Smith        2020-04-06T02:56:51Z
```

I need to remove the records under "LastActivity (UTC Time)" that are below the first date
Anything below: 2020-04-16
Then run a Get-ADUser command on Active Directory to get the samAccountName for each record and put it into a third column.

```
DisplayName        LastActivity (UTC Time)       UserID
-----------        -----------------------       ------
Tom Smith          2020-04-16T01:00:47Z          tsmith
Joe Bloggs         2020-04-16T01:00:47Z          jbloggs
Harry Briggs       2020-04-16T01:00:47Z          hbloggs
Jeff Kerry         2020-04-16T01:00:47Z          jkerry
```

Been testing a whole bunch of methods to Get-ADUser from ActiveDirectory to return the samaccountname, it will only work for one record when I use static text

```
Get-ADUser -filter { DisplayName -eq 'Tom Smith' } | Select samAccountName
```

Not when I import the csv file and run a foreach loop for each row.
The code I have tested, which I would think shuld return what I need is below:

```
$in_file = "C:\PS\SessionData\sessionTMSct.csv"
$out_file = "C:\PS\SessionData\sessionTMSctout.csv"

$out_data = @()

ForEach ($row in (Import-Csv $in_file)) {
    If ($row.DisplayName) {
        $out_data += Get-ADUser $row.DisplayName -Properties samAccountName
    }
} 

$out_data | 
Select DisplayName,'LastActivity (UTC Time)',SamAccountName | 
Export-Csv -Path $out_file -NoTypeInformation
```

Ends in the following error, pre row:

```
Get-ADUser : The term 'Get-ADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:8 char:22
+         $out_data += Get-ADUser $row.DisplayName -Properties samAccou ...
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-ADUser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Show your attempted code where you are importing the csv and running the foreach loop

Comment: @Itchydon - i have added the code that I have tested the foreach loop with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there. A custom field is what you need:

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\TeamsUserActivity.csv" | `
Where-Object { $PSItem.DisplayName -notlike "*-*" } | `
Select-Object -Property DisplayName,'LastActivity (UTC Time)',`
@{l="samAccountName";e={$DN = $_.DisplayName; `
(Get-ADUser -filter {DisplayName -eq $DN}).samAccountName}} | `
Export-CSV -path "C:\ExportedTeamsUserActivity.csv"
```

Comment: oh snap, ur right, was almost there. That has given me the third column wtih the samaccountname. Thank you.

Comment: How can I remove the "LastActivity (UTC Time)" values that are after: 2020-04-16..... ? e.g. 2020-04-15..... or 2020-04-14...... etc.

Comment: Or do I need to put a manual Where clause in there to filter the LastActivity values? Where-Object { $PSItem.Activity -eq '2020-04-16*' }

Comment: You might want to convert that field as a custom field to a `[datetime]` value, then you will be able to filter it with a `Where-Object {}` (or short: `? {}`).

Comment: Could be something like `? {$_.Time -gt ((Get-Date).AddDays(-10))}` after adding a custom Time field.